# How can I get a numbered check list in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, pandoc

How can I get a numbered check list? E.g.:

```
- TODO Organize party [2/4]
  1. [-] call people [1/3]
    - [ ] Peter
    - [X] Sarah
    - [ ] Sam
  2. [X] order food
  3. [ ] think about what music to play
  4. [X] talk to the neighbors
```

With this syntax, using Pandoc to make the conversion to HTML5, I get the tick-boxes displayed over the numbers.

Is this a Pandoc bug or I am using the wrong syntax?

References:
[Org-mode documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html)

Comment: Why are you using `pandoc`? Org mode can export to HTML5 natively and the above file looks fine when so exported. That said, I also did a `pandoc` transformation to HTML5 (with `pandoc 2.14.0.3`) and that *also* worked fine. So try exporting without pandoc and see if that works: `C-c C-e h o`. I would try updating `pandoc`, try again, and maybe look under the covers at the resulting HTML file to see if something looks wrong. But in any case, problems with `pandoc` are *not* appropriate for this **EMACS** site.

Comment: @NickD - I did not notice that Org-mode can do the conversion to HTML on its own. If you move it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @NickD - I wrote my question on the Emacs site because I thought Org-mode was part of the Emacs project.

Comment: Org mode *is* part of Emacs - what I was pointing out is that the question was about `pandoc` which is NOT part of Emacs. No big deal though: it's just something to keep in mind when you are asking questions (on any site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Made comment into an answer]

Why are you using pandoc? Org mode can export to HTML5 natively and the above file looks fine when so exported.  So try exporting without pandoc and see if that works: `C-c C-e h o`.

As for `pandoc`, I would try updating it, and trying the conversion again. One way to debug such problems is to open the HTML file in Emacs and see what it looks like. You will need to familiarize yourself with HTML a bit, but after some practice, you can figure out what the problem is fairly easily.

That said, I also did a `pandoc` transformation to `HTML5`, using `pandoc 2.14.0.3`, and that also worked fine: the numbers and the boxes and the check marks are in the right places. It looks slightly different from the Org-mode-produced HTML, but I think that's a matter of different styling.